# APA (bibliographystyle): Change language or symbol between two authors

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I really like the APA-citationstyle. But I need to change the "and" (english) connecting two authors into "und" (german). Check my MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage, totoc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[language=ngerman]{natbib}               
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                         

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{thaler2003libertarian,
  title={Libertarian paternalism},
  author={Thaler, Richard H and Sunstein, Cass R},
  journal={American Economic Review},
  pages={175--179},
  year={2003},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
\end{filecontents}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Introduction}

Text here \citep[p. 210]{thaler2003libertarian}.

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{\jobname} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You should make a copy of your `apalike.bst` file (for example `apalikeund.bst` - and put it into the folder of your main `.tex` file) and make the following changes to the new file.

Find the following function:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
```

Inside it, find

```
if$
          t "others" =
            { " et~al." * }
            { " and " * t * }
```

and change that `" and "` into `" und "`. This will do it for the bibliography. For the main text, you should do the same thing with the function

`FUNCTION {format.lab.names}`

Inside it, find the following strings:

```
{ " et~al." * }
{ " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

And change again `" and "` into `" und "`.

Of course you should also change `\bibliographystyle{apa}` by using the name of the new file (e.g. `\bibliographystyle{apalikeund}`).

Comment: And by 'edit `apalike.bst`' you really mean 'make a copy of it, and call it something else'. :) It's never a good idea to edit core packages of the distribution.

Comment: Well, good to know. What could happen if you edit the apalike.bst file? Nothing bad happened to my files, so I thought it was safe. Sorry for that :)

Comment: Two things: (i) now documents that want to use the original `apalike` style won't work, and (ii) any update of your TeX distribution could overwrite your changes. (Not terribly likely in this specific case, but an definite possibility in the general case.)

Comment: Thanks again. Edited both the answer and my .bst file. :)