# Citation call-outs should use "og" rather than "and" - English to Norwegian

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I use ShareLatex as the front-end tool for writing a master's thesis in Norwegian. My problem is that when I cite publications with two authors, the authors' names in the citation call-outs are separated by "and" and not "og" - the Norwegian word for "and".
I am using `natbib`.

I think the solution is to use the function

```
\renewcommand{\cite}{...}
```

But I am stuck here. Is there any good advice from anyone here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. Please also tell us which document class you use.

Comment: Thanks! I am not only new here, but also i Latex, so excuse the missing elements in my question:)

I use \documentclass[12pt]{article} and \bibliographystyle{apa}.

Comment: It would be automatic using `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277103/apa-bibliographystyle-change-language-or-symbol-between-two-authors/324037) answer which solves the question for the German language.

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful, but another problem - how do I find the .bts-file in Sharelatex? Or should I upload one?

Comment: TeXnically, the older answer to which you provide a link to discusses modifying the `apalike` and not the `apa` bibliography style. Fortunately, the two style files are quite similar in many ways, including the use (in two instances)  of the hard-coded string `" and "`.

Comment: @Adrian - The file `apa.bst` may be found in the CTAN sites, say, at `https://ctan.org/pkg/apabst`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Thank you so much!

I had to change my Latex-editor, but that was something I had to do anyway.

1. Downloaded Texpad
2. Downloaded the apa.bts
3. Modified the apa.bts file as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324037/145988).

Then I moved the file in to */usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bst/apa-copy.bst*

And last I changed my bibliography from

```
\bibliographystyle{apa}
```

to

```
\bibliographystyle{apa-copy}
```

And now it works!! I am so happy!